# JPA/hibernate - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails - BUT record exists

Tags: hibernate, jpa, foreign-keys

I'm having a strange problem.  I have some records in the database:

Company

- id = 1, Name = Microsoft
- id = 2, Name = Sun

Now I have another entity, Event which has a foreign key reference to Company:

```
@Entity
public class Event {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Company company;
}
```

In my web service layer, I create an Event using a company ID passed as a URL param:

```
@GET
@Path("addEvent")
public String addEvent(@QueryParam("cid") long companyId) {
    Company alreadyInDB = new Company();
    alreadyInDB.setId(companyId);

    Event event = new Event();
    event.setCompany(alreadyInDB);
    eventService.addEvent(event);
}
```

This than calls the EventService.  I originally was using the line of code commented out.  But when that failed with the foreign key constraint failure, I added the code to ensure the Company record exists.  Sure enough, the code prints out the proper ID.  But it still fails with a foreign key constraint violation.

```
@Service("eventService")
public class EventService {

    @Autowired
    EventDAO eventDAO;

    @Autowired
    CompanyDAO companyDAO;

    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor=Exception.class) 
    public void addEvent(Event event) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Company ID: " + event.getCompany().getId());

        Company ensureRecordExists = companyDAO.findById(event.getCompany().getId());
        System.out.println("ensureRecordExists: " + ensureRecordExists.getId());
        event.setCompany(ensureRecordExists);
        //event.setCompany(companyDAO.getReferenceById(event.getCompany().getId()));
        eventDAO.persist(event);
    }
}
```

Here's the relevant part of the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`blah`.`event`, CONSTRAINT `FKE7E9BF09F9DCA789` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `Company` (`id`))
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
```

Any idea what's going on?  I can physically see the record exists in mysql workbench.  I have no idea why it's failing.  I thought it might have something to do with flushing the session or some transactional issue...?  But I see the record...

Comment: The @JoinColumn(name="COMPANY_ID") seems to be missing in Event?

Comment: Thanks.  Same issue.  Maybe I should read the hibernate manual...   Actually, I've omitted @JoinColumn everywhere and in all other places it seemed to work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I narrowed the problem down and posted another question here:

[JPA/Hibernate - Entity name seems to be important. If I rename to "Bob" works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495062/jpa-hibernate-entity-name-seems-to-be-important-if-i-rename-to-bob-works-fin)

I found the solution here:

http://developmentality.wordpress.com/2011/05/23/hibernate-mysql-mac-foreign-key-nightmares-a-painless-solution-to-a-painful-problem/

Due to the combination of mysql, hibernate, and mac os x, there's some issue where you have to use a lowercase naming strategy in hibernate.  Hibernate by default uses a camel case naming strategy.

Answer (score 3):

You have to mention the  @JoinColumn

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
private Company company;
```

This is responsible for creating the company_id on the Event table.

Comment: I'm not sure why it matters, but my Company table references another entity, Building with a @ManyToOne relationship.  If I comment out that column, then the EventService saves fine.  It looks like I will have to do some reading so I fully understand Hibernate, but any thoughts on why this may be happening?